# Does anybody know how to disable the sound notification when switching desktops?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, system-sounds

That sound when switching desktops in Windows 10 is terrible and is driving me nuts.
Does anybody know how to disable that?

Comment: Is it just that specific event you want to silence? Or all System sounds?

Comment: Control panel (icon view)>sound>sounds tab, find the sound in there and change it to something more tolerable, or set the Scheme to No Sounds

Comment: I do not find the specific sound in that list is the problem.
Of course, I need other notification sounds, like email for e.g.,

Comment: In Control Panel, Sounds, what about System Notification and Windows Change Theme?   There is no sound in any of my Windows 10 Machines when I change Desktops, so it seems it might be something you had set at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In the default sound scheme there is no sound played on switching desktops.

To restore your sounds to the default scheme, right-click the volume icon in the system tray and choose Sound. (Also available by opening Control Panel and typing Sound.) Then click the Sounds tab:

[image]

When you view the Sounds tab, you may see a different sound scheme selected, or you may see that the currently selected scheme has been modified:

[image]

In this case you may first wish to save all the sound settings as they currently are, which can be done using the save button. Windows prompts you to choose a name for your custom sound scheme.